# Proving that composition distributes over copairing

Tags: category-theory

I'm familiar with the universal property of coproducts, but I have no idea how to prove something like $h \circ [ f, g ] \equiv [ h \circ f, h \circ g ]$. The diagram obviously commutes, but I can't see how you'd prove this with the category + coproduct identities.

How might I go about this?

Comment: What does $\langle f + g \rangle$ mean?

Comment: It's the copairing of f and g / eliminator for the coproduct. The unique arrow given by the universal property.

Comment: You mean, $f, g$ are two morphisms $f : a \to c, g : b \to c$, and $\langle f + g \rangle$ is the morphism $a \sqcup b \to c$ whose components are $f$ and $g$?

Comment: Yep, that's right

Comment: The notation I've usually seen for that is $[f,g]$. $f+g$ is the bifunctorial action, and $\langle f,g\rangle$ is commonly used for the pairing map for products. I've never seen $\langle f+g\rangle$.

Comment: As to your actual question, in the formulation of universal properties via representability, this is just naturality of the natural isomorphism witnessing representability.

Comment: @DerekElkins thanks for stopping by. I've updated the notation in my question. I haven't learned about representability. Do you have any suggestions for reading material?

The reason I posted the question in the first place is that I build categories and coproducts in Agda, and I'm trying to prove that the coproduct is unique up to isomorphism. I can construct the correct to- and from- arrows, but I can't prove that they're isomorphisms.

Comment: I cover various formulations of the notion of a universal property [here](https://www.hedonisticlearning.com/posts/styles-of-category-theory.html), but it is a topic that will be covered in any textbook on category theory, e.g. Awodey's.